# Styled Component Error with specific amount of styled instances

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I am currently receiving the following error when running my jest tests from styled component:

> Trying to insert a new style tag, but the given Node is unmounted!
>
> - Are you using a custom target that isn't mounted?
> - Does your document not have a valid head element?
> - Have you accidentally removed a style tag manually?

This is for the following code:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Heading } from "./heading";
import { MTButton } from "mtbutton";
import styled from "styled-components";

type FactsProperties = {
    facts: any;
    title: string;
    articleURL: string;
};

type FactsState = {
    currentFact: any;
};

const FactsDiv = styled.div`
    text-align: center;
`;

const FactDiv = styled.div`
    display: flex;
`;

const PageButton = styled.button`
    cursor: pointer;
`;
```

When I remove the bottom `PageButton` declaration, it works. It seems I can only put 2 styled declarations in this file before I receive the above error. I have styled components 4.4.1 pinned in all my dependencies as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the answer is in how jest deals with modules. After putting the following in `jest.config.js` this is back to working correctly:

```
  moduleDirectories: [
    "<rootDir>/node_modules",
    "node_modules"
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error when adding an additional call to `styled`.

In my case, updating `styled-components` to v5 (5.3.3) and `jest-styled-components` to v7 (7.0.8) solved the problem. However, I am still not sure what the underlying problem is.